# How to set a custom UIView's height according to its width given by auto layout?

Tags: ios, autolayout

Just like the UILabel does. If you set the numberOfLines 0, it will automatically calculating a height according to the width by auto layout.

Comment: you can use aspect ratio for the UIView in design builder and it will maintain the ratio if you change its height or width. but make sure you change its height or width through constraint only even at run time.

Comment: Thanks, but the situation cannot be solved by adding a ratio. As I write, it is just like the UILable, the height is decided by the width and its content.